# Ruby Grape - Pass Bigint as parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-grape, grape-api

Here is an API call I am writing. It works with INTEGER. However in the PostgreSQL DB the Hospital_ID is BIGINT.

```
desc "All Hospital Locations"
params do
  requires :authtoken, type: String, desc: "auth token"
  requires :hospitalid, type: Integer, desc: "hospital ID"
  #requires :hospitalid, type: Virtus::Attribute::Bigint, desc: "hospital ID"
  #Virtus::Attribute::Boolean,
end
```

I want to be able to pass BIGINT or similar variable.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you considered typing hospitalid as a string, and then casting it bigint in the receiver?

Comment: Please add more details over here

Comment: Right now, I have typing Bigint as a string and it is working..... Trying to see if there are other ways....